# SQL | Getting row number with ordered table & using WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm lost in my task. I need to get from this table
https://i.gyazo.com/06ebc5b1d070d3be638243cd366dc9a4.png

row position ordered by pocetHlasovani DESC when I have a serverNick, for example "Unknown".

Any solution?

Comment: Your mysql version ?

Comment: 5.7.21 blank blank

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `count()` all the rows with a "higher" `pocethlasovani`.

```
SELECT count(*)
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE t1.pocethlasovani >= (SELECT t2.pocethlasovani
                                          FROM elbat t2
                                          WHERE t2.servernick = 'Unknown');
```

`servernick` should be unique for this to work.